# Найти последовательность из N слов в тексте

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

У меня есть список из 2048 слов. Каждое от 3 до 8 букв включительно в нижнем регистре (латиница).

```
['pupil', 'culture', 'duty', 'gym', 'august', 'embark', 'artefact', ...]
```

И есть текст, в котором среди прочих слово могут быть заданные слова.

Задача: проверить этот текст, есть ли в нем 3 слова из списка выше и идут ли они один за одним (подряд). Между словами могут быть: символы переноса строки, скобки, пробелы, точки и цифры. Всего - не больше 5 символов (длина между словами). Например, слова в тексте могут выглядеть так:

```
1. august 2. embark 3. artefact
```

Либо так:

```
1. august
2. embark
3. artefact
```

А могут и так:

```
august embark artefact
```

Или так:

```
1) august 2) embark 3) artefact
```

Я нашел способ отследить, есть ли в тексте как минимум 3 слова из всего списка (но этого не достаточно для решения задачи):

```
list_words = ['pupil', 'culture', 'duty', 'gym', 'august', 'embark', 'artefact']

simple_text = """
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
1. august 2. embark 3. artefact
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
"""

count_find_words = 0
for word in list_words:
    if word in simple_text:
        count_find_words += 1
        if count_find_words == 3:
            print('Последовательность есть в тексте!')
            break
```

Подскажите способ для поиска последовательности из 3 слов в тексте.

***Задача со звездочкой**:
Добавить в решение возможность поиска не 3 слова подряд, а более. Лучше - возможность регулировать это число.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно из текста выделить все слова:

```
def get_words(text):
    for m in re.finditer(r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b', text):
        yield m.group(0)
```

Вот так словарные слова собираются в группы и для каждой группы возвращается её длина:

```
def lengths(vocabulary, text):
    for f, g in itertools.groupby(get_words(text), key=lambda w: w in vocabulary):
        if f:
            yield sum(1 for _ in g)
```

Вот так ищется достаточно длинная группа:

```
def find_long_group(min_length, words, text):
    return any(length >= min_length for length in lengths(words, text))
```

Так это всё тестируется:

```
def test():
    list_words = ['pupil', 'culture', 'duty', 'gym', 'august', 'embark', 'artefact']
    simple_text = """
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    1. august 2. embark 3. artefact
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
    """

    print(find_long_group(4, set(list_words), simple_text))
    print(find_long_group(3, set(list_words), simple_text))
```

**P.S.** Отдельно вариант с печатью найденной группы:

```
import itertools
import re


def get_words(text):
    for m in re.finditer(r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b', text):
        yield m.group(0)


def find_long_group(min_length, vocabulary, text):
    for f, g in itertools.groupby(get_words(text), key=lambda w: w in vocabulary):
        if f:
            g = tuple(g)
            if len(g) >= min_length:
                yield g


def test():
    list_words = ['pupil', 'culture', 'duty', 'gym', 'august', 'embark', 'artefact']
    simple_text = """
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    1. august 2. embark 3. artefact
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
    """

    print(next(find_long_group(3, set(list_words), simple_text), None))
    print(next(find_long_group(4, set(list_words), simple_text), None))


test()
```

Comment: Благодарю. А может еще подскажете функцию для выборки последовательности из текста? То есть, вывести последовательность слов, которая нашлась в тексте.

Comment: Не знаю как вы это сдавать будете. Никто не поверит. :)

Comment: Вроде все ок, только всегда возвращается максимальная последовательность слов. А нужна точная: если указал 10, то должно искать только последовательность из 10 слов. Не больше и не меньше.

Comment: Уверен, вам не составит труда исправить мой код. Потребуется заменить один символ.